# FIles sharing through wifi in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to make an application which can send files through wifi.Can any tech gig please help me ?

Comment: Depends how much you are paying - Stack Overflow is not your code monkey!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make direct access to the contents of the Smartphone via WiF. I know this is one of the security features of the OS.

But you can make the sharing of content through a transient storage in the cloud.